# How to redirect user to another page after expiration date by php

Tags: php

I have order (Master) and Test (Child) tables. Master table has "target_date" field. I want to prevent user to add new record in child table (Test) after the target_date in Master record has expired. I used the following code for testing to redirect to another page with no luck.

I just created a view table from the original child table without "add button" and use this table to redirect from original child table after expired date.

I put this code on child_listpage: Before Process event. It should work, but some reason it does not. When user click on the original child (Test) table link on the Master record page then it should redirect to the child_view page if the target_date on Master table has expired.

I would appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

```
function BeforeProcessList(&$conn, &$pageObject)
{
    $target_date = "05-01-2014"; 

    if($target_date == date("m-d-Y",time()))
    {
       header("Location: testview_list.php");
       exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` statement checks with `==`, so the code will only run on that exact date, not any date afterwards.

Comment: Thank for catch. I changed '==' to '<=' but that was not work too.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
function BeforeProcessList(&$conn, &$pageObject)
{
   $target_date = new DateTime("05-01-2014");
   $today = new DateTime(); 
   if((int)$target_date->diff($today)->format('%r%a') >= 0)
   {
      header("Location: testview_list.php");
      exit();
   }
}
```

Comment: This one not even redirected rather stuck. Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah but that will fix your issue on comparison that you just compare dates to be equal not greater than; You're welcome. I also changed my mistake from `<=` to `>=`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, comparing with `==` is only ever going to make a redirect happen on one exact date. Secondly, rather than converting the current date to a string, you want to convert your *target* date to a *timestamp*, so you can do mathematical comparisons with it:

```
// Note changed date format, just to be unambiguous
// I'm guessing you meant May 1st not Jan 5th
$target_date = "2014-05-01"; 

if ( strtotime($target_date) <= time() ) {
     // etc
}
```

Alternatively, you could use [DateTime objects](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), in much the same way:

```
$target_date = "2014-05-01"; 

if ( new DateTime($target_date) <= new DateTime() ) {
     // etc
}
```

Comment: Both `if` statements work for me: http://3v4l.org/edhCS http://3v4l.org/eGsJ3 If you have other problems, you will need to debug those separately.